# Does a C program runs on all processor cores by default?

Tags: c, parallel-processing

I am designing a processor-intensive program in C using the Codeblocks IDE on Windows 8. I assume that by default, since my code is un-optimized, the minute I run it, it will only run on 1 core of my processor, leaving the other 3 cores idle.

Is my assumption correct? If yes, does using something like OpenMP to optimize my code will make it run faster? I am processing a list of data-sets and each data-set is independent of the other one. There is no dependability among them.

Comment: It depends on several factors and is at the discretion of OS I believe. How many processes/threads are you creating in the program?. How many cores are idle at the moment your program is loaded?

Comment: So I just checked it on my i7 with 8 logical cores. Only CPU 5 shows heavy loading while the other CPUs sit idle.

Comment: Are you asking if you don't use threading or OpenMP, will your code always execute on **one** core, or the **same** core? There quite a distinction between the two, and I hope that is clear.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant the code will execute on one core, it might be any of the available cores and might change randomly each time the code is launched.

Comment: If on Linux or some Posix, read a [Posix threads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default your code will only run on one core.

If you have low dependability between threads, then running something like OpenMP should make your code run faster. How much faster depends on how much of your code is parallelizable.